# How to reorder "Apply Discount Code" field on last step of checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml, magento2.1.5

I would like to reorder the "Apply Discount Code" to the top of the payment step. I had a customer who complained that the order of these elements indicated it was to be entered after payment, and so she accidentally paid before adding her coupon.

[image: Goal: reorder Apply Discount Code]

Here is what I've tried so far.

```
// File: <theme>/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
  <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
   <arguments>
    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
           <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                  <!-- <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> -->
                 </item>
                </item>
               </item>
              </item>
             </item>
            </item>
           </item>
          </item>
         </item>
        </item>
       </item>
      </item>
     </item>
    </argument>
   </arguments>
  </referenceBlock>
 </body>
</page>
```

I left the `componentDisabled` item in my example so I could mention that if I uncomment it, the "Apply Discount Code" field disappears. This tells me I'm doing something right.

Besides the above example, I've also tried nesting `<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>` inside `<item name="config" xsi:type="array">`, to no avail. Lastly, I've tried a range of numbers including 500, 99999, 0 and -99999.

My guess is there is no way to surpass the sortOrder given to the payment methods group and so they need to be change but I don't know how. Can anyone help?

Comment: I just noticed `afterMethods` which I'm guessing is payment methods, that's probably the part I want to target... going to try looking into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution involved what I did above in my commented-out XML in the question. I removed the discount code from the `<afterMethods>` block and then copied it from magento's source so that it appears in the `<beforeMethods>` sections. The XML I copied to re-add the discount is from

`/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

Here is my final XML:

```
#File: <theme>/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
  <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
   <arguments>
    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
           <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="beforeMethods" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
                 <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount-messages</item>
                   <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                  </item>
                 </item>
                </item>
               </item>
              </item>
              <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                 </item>
                </item>
               </item>
              </item>
             </item>
            </item>
           </item>
          </item>
         </item>
        </item>
       </item>
      </item>
     </item>
    </argument>
   </arguments>
  </referenceBlock>
 </body>
</page>
```

After that some simple style updates to remove an awkward border.